# Are CMYK toners fluorescent in typical color laser printers?

Tags: cmyk, print-production

A typical laser color printer uses four toner colors (cyan, magenta, yellow and black) to be able to print different colors. Are the individual toner colors typically daylight fluorescent? For example if you printed a pure magenta square on non-OBA paper, would the square be fluorescent? I am asking because they look very bright.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, but why not test it and see?  Use an ultraviolet light to check.

Comment: Good idea - need to get non-OBA paper because the ink coverage isn't complete when I print a 'solid color' block. I am thinking that UV may not show whether the toners are fluorescent if they are excited outside the UV range (like hunter orange or safety green are).

Answer (score 2):

In the true meaning of the word "Fluorescent": no, they are not.

(after-market Fluorescent toners are available)

Comment: Thanks, I changed 'ink' to 'toner' in the question. I am curious: Why would someone want to use the aftermarket fluorescent toners you mention? A bigger printing gamut?

Comment: I imagine if someone wanted to print something for signage to be used in night clubs, or similar.

Comment: Here is an example which seems to be aimed at that application, https://www.oki.com/uk/printing/about-us/news-room/press-releases/2016/0401/index.html